# Query to find data between particular row number in Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am implementing paging in my .net application, and I want to fetch data as per the page number so for example if I am having total 100 items and showing 10 items per page and if user click on "2" it should show Items from 11 to 20, and I want to fetch only data from mongo which is between 11 to 20, I know how to do this in SQL but I am new to Mongo.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution that doesn't scale up very well is :

`db.col.find(..).skip(i * s).limit(s)` where i = page number (0 based) and s = page size (10 in your case).

As I mentioned this solution does not work very well for large amounts of data since skip(N) is an o(N) operation and will slow down as N increases. Solutions that do scale are more complex and generally situational in nature.